# Calculating approximate dose of UVs received by a virus

Tags: virology, uv, dose

I am making a very approximate calculation to determine the dose of UVs received by a virus standing at 1.5 cm from a UV source during a certain amount of time. Please let me know if my train of thought is incorrect.

Suppose I use an LED that emits 2mW of radiant flux. Side comment: I found one that with that draws 20mA of current when a forward voltage of 6.5 V is applied, which leads to a power draw of 130 mW. Thus LED efficiency is 2mW/130mW= 1.67%. I though LEDs are very efficient...)

To avoid making complicated calculations, suppose that 80% of all the flux is concentrated in 45 degree cone. In addition, supposing that the flux per cm2 is constant (I don't know the name for that value) on a flat circle area at a 1.5cm distance from the light source and where the virus will be placed. The LED will be switched on for 5 seconds. As such, the dose received by the virus is:

$$
Dose = 80\%* \frac{2mW}{(pi*(1.5cm)^2)}*5sec
$$

Is that equation correct?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question doesn't seems like it is a good fit for this site since it isn't directly about biology. Thanks! 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about estimating a physical parameter (radiation flux) rather than biology.

Comment: which SE site should I post this to?

Comment: Maybe [Physics.SE] or [Engineering.SE]? I'm not familiar with either of those sites, so please make sure you read up on the standards for each site and check them for similar questions before reposting.

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid making complicated calculations, suppose that 80% of all the flux is concentrated in 45 degree cone.

The actual distribution of light is probably nothing like that.  Diodes tend to put significant amounts of power at higher angles so that way less than 80% ends up in the center, and within the central spot they peak at the center and then gradually drop off:  https://photonsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/280nm-LED-performance-informationV3.pdf

Usually beam patterns are either simulated from manufacturer ray data or measured.  Since you're looking at low power and very low efficiency diodes, and given how much UVC LEDs cost, I'm guessing these are surplus or below-spec parts being sold on ebay or similar and you don't have access to the underlying datasheets.  In that case this is a reasonable way to estimate.